# Use aws sso to execute sls commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, npx

I am running below command to list all the CloudFormation stack outputs.

```
npx sls info --stage $STAGE --verbose
```

Upon executing I am getting below error

> ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure: Profile default not found

I can definitely use aws access and secret keys to use `sls` commands but I am trying to achieve this using AWS SSO. SSO basically stores temporary credentials in ~/.aws/sso/cache/****.json, I am able to execute all other commands to communicate with AWS using this method but somehow sls commands aren't working.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work by using [serverless-better-credentials](https://github.com/thomasmichaelwallace/serverless-better-credentials).

Install with:

```
npm install serverless-better-credentials
```

Then add to `serverless.yml` plugins, so that it appears first in the list:

```
plugins:
   - serverless-better-credentials
```